# How to affix items like paperclips to a surface?

Tags: adhesives

I have a craft idea that involves affixing paperclips in a pattern onto a surface (painted wood or clay). What kind of adhesive would firmly attach the clips but remain invisible? Thanks!

Comment: Are the paperclips going to be flush against the surface, or is just one wire going to be contact (so that they are sticking out)?

Answer (score 0):

I’d try lecture ultra gel adhesive! I haven’t tried it on wood but I use it for a lot of different materials and they have different kinds for different surfaces.

Comment: What materials have you used it for? As it stand, this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: You’re right! Sorry I’m new and still getting used to the format of the site! I’ve mainly used it for fabric and metal. It’s one of the only glues I’ve had work well for fabric so I thought I’d mention it.